# Generic type operands in custom Swift operator

Tags: swift, operators

My aim is to create an operator that will allow me to easily merge `Dictionary` values, eg:

```
["a" : "A"] + ["b" : "B"]
```

My attempt below:

```
extension Dictionary {
    public static func +=<K, V>(lhs: inout Dictionary<K, V>, rhs: Dictionary<K, V>?) {
        if let rhs = rhs {
            lhs.merge( rhs )
        }
    }

    public static func +=<K, V>(lhs: inout Dictionary<K, V>?, rhs: Dictionary<K, V>) {
        if var lhs = lhs {
            lhs.merge( rhs )
        }
        else {
            lhs = rhs
        }
    }

    public static func +<K, V>(lhs: Dictionary<K, V>, rhs: Dictionary<K, V>?) -> Dictionary<K, V> {
        if let rhs = rhs {
            return lhs.merging( rhs )
        }

        return lhs
    }

    public static func +<K, V>(lhs: Dictionary<K, V>?, rhs: Dictionary<K, V>) -> Dictionary<K, V> {
        if let lhs = lhs {
            return lhs.merging( rhs )
        }

        return rhs
    }

    @inlinable public mutating func merge(_ other: [Key: Value]) {
        self.merge( other, uniquingKeysWith: { $1 } )
    }

    @inlinable public func merging(_ other: [Key: Value]) -> [Key: Value] {
        self.merging( other, uniquingKeysWith: { $1 } )
    }
}
```

This does not appear to work (as of Swift 5), and I suspect the issue is related to the `Dictionary` type being a generic type.  Anyone that can explain what's inhibiting this from working and whether there's an alternative solution/approach that can work?

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't recommend this. `dictA.merging(dictB, uniquingKeysWith: { $1 } )` is not that long, and is pretty clear what's going on. Where as by just glossing it over as `merging`, it's unclear what collision resolution approach is taking place. Let along using `+`, `+=`, where nobody will know what's going on without following all the implementation bread crumbs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem there is that you are creating new generic `K`, `V` value types. All you need is to omit them in your methods declaration. Btw you forgot to add a method to sum two non optional dictionaries:

```
extension Dictionary {

    public static func +=(lhs: inout Dictionary, rhs: Dictionary) {
         lhs.merge(rhs)
    }
    public static func +=(lhs: inout Dictionary, rhs: Dictionary?) {
        if let rhs = rhs { lhs.merge(rhs) }
    }
    public static func +=(lhs: inout Dictionary?, rhs: Dictionary) {
        if var lhs = lhs { lhs.merge(rhs) } else { lhs = rhs }
    }

    public static func +(lhs: Dictionary, rhs: Dictionary) -> Dictionary {
        lhs.merging(rhs)
    }
    public static func +(lhs: Dictionary, rhs: Dictionary?) -> Dictionary {
        if let rhs = rhs { return lhs.merging(rhs) }
        return lhs
    }
    public static func +(lhs: Dictionary?, rhs: Dictionary) -> Dictionary {
        if let lhs = lhs { return lhs.merging(rhs) }
        return rhs
    }

    @inlinable public mutating func merge(_ other: Dictionary) {
        self.merge(other) {$1}
    }

    @inlinable public func merging(_ other: Dictionary) -> Dictionary {
        self.merging(other) {$1}
    }
}
```

---

```
let dicSum = ["a" : "A"] + ["b" : "B"]

dicSum  // ["b": "B", "a": "A"]
```

---

An alternative is to create typealiases for Dictionary generic Key and Value types and remove those you have created in your methods declaration `<K,V>` otherwise they would be again a new generic type unrelated to the ones defined at the Dictionary [declaration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary):

```
extension Dictionary {

    public typealias K = Key
    public typealias V = Value

    public static func +=(lhs: inout [K: V], rhs: [K: V]) {
         lhs.merge(rhs)
    }
    public static func +=(lhs: inout [K: V], rhs: [K: V]?) {
        if let rhs = rhs { lhs.merge(rhs) }
    }
    public static func +=(lhs: inout [K: V]?, rhs: [K: V]) {
        if var lhs = lhs { lhs.merge(rhs) } else { lhs = rhs }
    }

    public static func +(lhs: [K: V], rhs: [K: V]) -> [K: V] {
        lhs.merging(rhs)
    }
    public static func +(lhs: [K: V], rhs: [K: V]?) -> [K: V] {
        if let rhs = rhs { return lhs.merging(rhs) }
        return lhs
    }
    public static func +(lhs: [K: V]?, rhs: [K: V]) -> [K: V] {
        if let lhs = lhs { return lhs.merging(rhs) }
        return rhs
    }

    @inlinable public mutating func merge(_ other: [K: V]) {
        self.merge(other) {$1}
    }

    @inlinable public func merging(_ other: [K: V]) -> [K: V] {
        self.merging(other) {$1}
    }
}
```

Which is exactly the same as what is being done above.

---

Again `Dictionary`, `Dictionary<Key, Value>` and `[Key:Value]` are exactly the same thing:

```
extension Dictionary {

    public static func +=(lhs: inout [Key: Value], rhs: [Key: Value]) {
         lhs.merge(rhs)
    }
    public static func +=(lhs: inout [Key: Value], rhs: [Key: Value]?) {
        if let rhs = rhs { lhs.merge(rhs) }
    }
    public static func +=(lhs: inout [Key: Value]?, rhs: [Key: Value]) {
        if var lhs = lhs { lhs.merge(rhs) } else { lhs = rhs }
    }

    public static func +(lhs: [Key: Value], rhs: [Key: Value]) -> [Key: Value] {
        lhs.merging(rhs)
    }
    public static func +(lhs: [Key: Value], rhs: [Key: Value]?) -> [Key: Value] {
        if let rhs = rhs { return lhs.merging(rhs) }
        return lhs
    }
    public static func +(lhs: [Key: Value]?, rhs: [Key: Value]) -> [Key: Value] {
        if let lhs = lhs { return lhs.merging(rhs) }
        return rhs
    }

    @inlinable public mutating func merge(_ other: [Key: Value]) {
        self.merge(other) {$1}
    }

    @inlinable public func merging(_ other: [Key: Value]) -> [Key: Value] {
        self.merging(other) {$1}
    }
}
```

---

All 3 ways to implement it are equivalent. Choose the one you feel comfortable with.

Comment: The idea of the generic types was to enforce that the types of the arguments and return value need to be compatible.  Omitting those generic types, how does the compiler know the types of the dictionaries are compatible (`merge` and `merging` for one, require the types to be compatible) or even what the return value of the `+` should be typed as?  I guess I'm not sure why this even works at all?

Comment: Dictionary `Key` and `Value` as you know already are generic types. The only requirement is that the key must be `Hashable`. You can combine any dictionary type using the merge method which only requires that the other `Sequence` `Element` needs to be a key-value pair. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127171-merge. Note that if combine two dictionaries with different key types the resulting dictionary `Key` will be inferred as `AnyHashable` and if you combine different `Value` types the resulting `Value` type will be inferred as `Any`

Comment: So how does Swift resolve the `Key` and `Value` of the return value of `+`?  Is it based on the operands?  The method signature doesn't seem to contain anything relating the `Key` of the operands to the `Key` of the return value.  Similarly, doesn't the `+=` operator's `merge` require that the `Key` and `Value` types of `lhs` are the same as those of `rhs` and how is that requirement met here? Or does this solution just completely erase all generic types and constraints?

Comment: `merge` and `+=` won't allow you to merge `Dictionary` with different key-value types

Comment: I'm not sure that answers the question of in what way the `Key` and `Value` types are inter-related between the operands and return `Dictionary`s.

Comment: @lhunath This answer solves your issue. Again you are creating two new generic types but in fact you need to use the ones already defined in Dictionary declaration. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary. If you don't understand why and how it works I can't really help you further. I don't mind if you mark this as the accepted answer or not. This is how you have to implement it.

Comment: Funny thing is that you have already implemented just by yourself the `merge` and `merging` methods the right way. Why you didn't do the same to the other methods really beats me.

Comment: If you create two new generic types, you would need to constrain `K == Key` and  `V == Value` but then a same-type requirement would make 'K' and 'Key' equivalent and that would make no sense.

Comment: Oh- I hadn't realized there's a hidden K and V type at play here that's shared between the operands.  Since we're in a static context as opposed to an instance context, I don't see how the first operand's K constraint relates to the second operand's K - I thought them independent and figured I needed to declare my own `Key` in order to inter-correlate them.  `merge` and `merging` are in an instance context so they have an existing `Key` and `Value` that can be referenced.